# Apache HttpAsyncClient not mapping http response to the right servlet request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, servlet-3.0, apache-httpcomponents

I've this code called from servlet service method.
The response from the asyncClient is not rightly mapped to the right servlet request. Is there anything I'm missing?

import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClients;

```
    final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync(request, response);      
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient asyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
    asyncClient.start();
    asyncClient.execute(httpRequestBase, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void completed(HttpResponse result) {

            try {
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)asyncContext.getResponse(); // and then, copied result values to response object.
                result.getEntity().writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        asyncContext.complete();
        }
}
```

Comment: Also before even 'completed' method is called, I get 500 error as response!

Comment: Is this the whole processing here? 
In my understanding result in callback refers to AsyncClient response, not HttpResponse that application calling your Servlet expects, cath all exceptions and add printStackTrace

Comment: yes..the HttpResponse result is copied to HttpServletResponse response..(included the code for body copy part). The problem I'm facing is, some how servlet response output stream is getting wrong values.